# Error Validating / Distributing to AppStore in Xcode - DVTFoundation.DVTCodeSignerError (0)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I got the error code DVTFoundation.DVTCodeSignerError (0) when trying to validate or distribute my app in Xcode.

I am having trouble figuring out what it is. I contacted Apple tech support and they said it was a Unity issue. But I can't find out anything about this particular error online.

Any clues? I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just at a loss for what might be causing it. I built the same app successfully a few days ago.

Xcode 13

Unity 2020.31f1

ARFoundation 4.0.12

ARKit 4.0.12

Comment: Fixed it. The error was:

<IDEDistributionCodesignStep: 0x7fc3c98e0fb0>" failed for distribution item "abci.bundle" with error "DVTFoundation.DVTCodeSignerError.signingFailed("/var/folders/6z/jy_wjt2d3hb9lq_62gylf28w0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~SrEoGT/Root/Payload/PolycoroTestApp.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/abci.bundle: unsealed contents present in the bundle root\n")"

One of the packages I had recently imported (Alembic) for some reason wasn't signed and so I could not validate of distribute my app.
I removed the offending package in Package Manager and that worked.